# Flask is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, flask

I have this weird looking error.
I'm new to flask idk what to do with the error flask is not recognized as internal or external command.
https://github.com/arnavnagpurkar/Pushups-logger
I have 3 files and i want all of them to run in order to have a good website but im getting this error.

Extra - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MAt-mRJk4rw&list=PLS1QulWo1RIZ6OujqIAXmLR3xsDn_ENHI&index=2&t=399s
Im following this tut

I was expecting that the app will run

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)